# My custom list choice column is appearing different on different devices during entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, choice-field

So I have some android Tablet E's at work and I have created an entry form for some data (custom list). The list should be showing check marks for the choice column so they may see all of them at once and check all that they want. It allows multiple choices and to enter your own value, but on one device it is appearing with the check marks and another it appears as a drop down and you cannot enter your own value or see all of them at the same time. Some people do not always realize it is a drop down and that they may select different options.
Thanks.

[image: This is the "Buggy" one]

This is the "Buggy" one.

[image: This is how I want it to appear]

This is how I want it to appear.